# Белый уголок в текстовом поле для ввода комментария в тёмной теме

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, комментарии, тёмная-тема

Собственно, вот:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ubuntu 20.04.1
Firefox 82.0

Comment: Стоит указать версии браузера и ОС, т.к. у меня это [выглядит вполне адекватно](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ek975.png).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ сделано

Comment: Да, на убунте тоже такое наблюдаю.

Comment: Вообще, если проблема актуальна для разных сайтов сети, то лучше постить сразу на MSE. Хотя и говорят, что баги по всем метам собирают, но на MSE к ним внимания всё же больше, чем тут. На MSO, кстати, может быть и ещё больше.

Comment: Debian 10 + chromium, не наблюдается

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 + Chromium, не наблюдается тоже.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Значит во всём виноват Firefox!